Decoupling CSTR simulation logic into sensors and PID control
Thank you so much for all of your useful tutorials. I am trying to relearn basic PID control from 10 years ago when I was back in Chem E.
I want to decouple your script. Could you help please?
Is it possible to split this script up into two parts where one script outputs Ca and Treactor and the other outputs Tc? At this point this is just for my own darn curiosity.
Coupled:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

# from IMC tuning
Kc = 4.61730615181 * 2.0
tauI = 0.913444964569 / 4.0
tauD = 0.0

# define CSTR model
def cstr(x, t, u, Tf, Caf):
    Tc = u
    Ca = x[0]
    T = x[1]
    q = 100
    V = 100
    rho = 1000
    Cp = 0.239
    mdelH = 5e4
    EoverR = 8750
    k0 = 7.2e10
    UA = 5e4
    rA = k0 * np.exp(-EoverR / T) * Ca

    # Calculate concentration derivative
    dCadt = q / V * (Caf - Ca) - rA
    # Calculate temperature derivative
    dTdt = q / V * (Tf - T) \
           + mdelH / (rho * Cp) * rA \
           + UA / V / rho / Cp * (Tc - T)

    # Return xdot:
    xdot = np.zeros(2)
    xdot[0] = dCadt
    xdot[1] = dTdt
    return xdot

# Steady State Initial Conditions for the States
Ca_ss = 0.87725294608097
T_ss = 324.475443431599
x0 = np.empty(2)
x0[0] = Ca_ss
x0[1] = T_ss

# Steady State Initial Condition
u_ss = 300.0
# Feed Temperature (K)
Tf = 350
# Feed Concentration (mol/m^3)
Caf = 1

# Time Interval (min)
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 301)

# storage for recording values
op = np.ones(len(t)) * u_ss  # controller output
pv = np.zeros(len(t))  # process variable
e = np.zeros(len(t))  # error
ie = np.zeros(len(t))  # integral of the error
dpv = np.zeros(len(t))  # derivative of the pv
P = np.zeros(len(t))  # proportional
I = np.zeros(len(t))  # integral
D = np.zeros(len(t))  # derivative
sp = np.ones(len(t)) * T_ss  # set point

# define a setpoint ramp or steps
for i in range(15):
    sp[i * 20:(i + 1) * 20] = 300 + i * 7.0
sp[300] = sp[299]

# Upper and Lower limits on OP
op_hi = 350.0
op_lo = 250.0

pv[0] = T_ss

# Loop through time steps    
for i in range(len(t) - 1):
    delta_t = t[i + 1] - t[i]
    e[i] = sp[i] - pv[i]
    if i >= 1:  # calculate starting on second cycle
        dpv[i] = (pv[i] - pv[i - 1]) / delta_t
        ie[i] = ie[i - 1] + e[i] * delta_t
    P[i] = Kc * e[i]
    I[i] = Kc / tauI * ie[i]
    D[i] = -Kc * tauD * dpv[i]
    op[i] = op[0] + P[i] + I[i] + D[i]
    if op[i] > op_hi:  # check upper limit
        op[i] = op_hi
        ie[i] = ie[i] - e[i] * delta_t  # anti-reset windup
    if op[i] < op_lo:  # check lower limit
        op[i] = op_lo
        ie[i] = ie[i] - e[i] * delta_t  # anti-reset windup
    ts = [t[i], t[i + 1]]
    u[i + 1] = op[i]
    y = odeint(cstr, x0, ts, args=(u[i + 1], Tf, Caf))
    Ca[i + 1] = y[-1][0]
    T[i + 1] = y[-1][1]
    x0[0] = Ca[i + 1]
    x0[1] = T[i + 1]
    pv[i + 1] = T[i + 1]

op[len(t) - 1] = op[len(t) - 2]
ie[len(t) - 1] = ie[len(t) - 2]
P[len(t) - 1] = P[len(t) - 2]
I[len(t) - 1] = I[len(t) - 2]
D[len(t) - 1] = D[len(t) - 2]

# Construct results and save data file
data = np.vstack((t, u, T, Ca, op)).T  # vertical stack and transpose data
np.savetxt('CSTR_simulator.txt', data, delimiter=',')

plt.ioff()
plt.show()
par

I tried this being the cstr:
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

# Define CSTR model
def cstr(x, t, u, Tf, Caf):
    Ca = x[0]
    T = x[1]

    q = 100
    V = 100
    rho = 1000
    Cp = 0.239
    mdelH = 5e4
    EoverR = 8750
    k0 = 7.2e10
    UA = 5e4
    rA = k0 * np.exp(-EoverR / T) * Ca

    dCadt = q / V * (Caf - Ca) - rA
    dTdt = q / V * (Tf - T) + mdelH / (rho * Cp) * rA + UA / V / rho / Cp * (u - T)

    xdot = np.zeros(2)
    xdot[0] = dCadt
    xdot[1] = dTdt
    return xdot

# Simulation function
def simulate_cstr(u, Tf, Caf, x0, t):
    Ca = np.ones(len(t)) * x0[0]
    T = np.ones(len(t)) * x0[1]
    for i in range(len(t) - 1):
        ts = [t[i], t[i + 1]]
        y = odeint(cstr, x0, ts, args=(u[i], Tf, Caf))
        Ca[i + 1] = y[-1][0]
        T[i + 1] = y[-1][1]
        x0[0] = Ca[i + 1]
        x0[1] = T[i + 1]
    return Ca, T

and this being the the controller
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cstr_reactor import simulate_cstr  # Assuming your file is named cstr_reactor.py

# PID parameters and initial conditions
Kc = 4.61730615181 * 2.0
tauI = 0.913444964569 / 4.0
tauD = 0.0

# Control loop
def pid_control(sp, T_ss, u_ss, t, Tf, Caf, x0):
    u = np.ones(len(t)) * u_ss
    op = np.ones(len(t)) * u_ss
    pv = np.zeros(len(t))
    e = np.zeros(len(t))
    ie = np.zeros(len(t))
    dpv = np.zeros(len(t))
    P = np.zeros(len(t))
    I = np.zeros(len(t))
    D = np.zeros(len(t))

    # Initialize Ca and T arrays
    Ca = np.ones(len(t)) * x0[0]
    T = np.ones(len(t)) * x0[1]

    # Upper and Lower limits on OP
    op_hi = 350.0
    op_lo = 250.0

    pv[0] = T_ss

    # Create plot
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
    plt.ion()
    plt.show()

    for i in range(len(t) - 1):
        delta_t = t[i + 1] - t[i]
        e[i] = sp[i] - pv[i]
        if i >= 1:
            dpv[i] = (pv[i] - pv[i - 1]) / delta_t
            ie[i] = ie[i - 1] + e[i] * delta_t
        P[i] = Kc * e[i]
        I[i] = Kc / tauI * ie[i]
        D[i] = -Kc * tauD * dpv[i]
        op[i] = op[0] + P[i] + I[i] + D[i]
        if op[i] > op_hi:
            op[i] = op_hi
            ie[i] = ie[i] - e[i] * delta_t
        if op[i] < op_lo:
            op[i] = op_lo
            ie[i] = ie[i] - e[i] * delta_t
        u[i + 1] = op[i]

        # Use the current Ca and T for the initial condition of the next step
        x0 = [Ca[i], T[i]]
        Ca, T = simulate_cstr(u, Tf, Caf, x0, t)
        pv[i + 1] = T[i + 1]

        # Debugging information
        if i % 50 == 0:
            print(f"Time: {t[i]:.2f}, Setpoint: {sp[i]:.2f}, PV: {pv[i]:.2f}, OP: {op[i]:.2f}, Ca: {Ca[i]:.2f}, T: {T[i]:.2f}")

        # Plot the results
        plt.clf()
        plt.subplot(4, 1, 1)
        plt.plot(t[0:i], u[0:i], 'b--', linewidth=3)
        plt.ylabel('Cooling T (K)')
        plt.legend(['Jacket Temperature'], loc='best')
        plt.subplot(4, 1, 2)
        plt.plot(t[0:i], Ca[0:i], 'g-', linewidth=3)
        plt.ylabel('Ca (mol/L)')
        plt.legend(['Reactor Concentration'], loc='best')

        plt.subplot(4, 1, 3)
        plt.plot(t[0:i], sp[0:i], 'r--', linewidth=2, label='Set Point')
        plt.plot(t[0:i], T[0:i], 'k:', linewidth=3, label='Reactor Temperature')
        plt.ylabel('T (K)')
        plt.xlabel('Time (min)')
        plt.legend(loc='best')
        plt.subplot(4, 1, 4)
        plt.plot(t[0:i], op[0:i], 'r--', linewidth=3, label='Controller Output (OP)')
        plt.plot(t[0:i], P[0:i], 'g:', linewidth=2, label='Proportional (Kc e(t))')
        plt.plot(t[0:i], I[0:i], 'b.-', linewidth=2, label='Integral (Kc/tauI * Int(e(t))')
        plt.plot(t[0:i], D[0:i], 'k-.', linewidth=2, label='Derivative (-Kc tauD d(PV)/dt)')
        plt.legend(loc='best')
        plt.ylabel('Output')
        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(0.01)

    op[len(t) - 1] = op[len(t) - 2]
    ie[len(t) - 1] = ie[len(t) - 2]
    P[len(t) - 1] = P[len(t) - 2]
    I[len(t) - 1] = I[len(t) - 2]
    D[len(t) - 1] = D[len(t) - 2]

    # Save data to file
    data = np.vstack((t, u, T, Ca, op)).T
    np.savetxt('data_doublet_steps.txt', data, delimiter=',')

    return u, T

# Main execution
if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = np.linspace(0, 10, 301)
    x0 = [0.87725294608097, 324.475443431599]
    sp = np.ones(len(t)) * 324.475443431599

    # Define a setpoint ramp or steps
    for i in range(15):
        sp[i * 20:(i + 1) * 20] = 300 + i * 7.0
    sp[300] = sp[299]

    u, T = pid_control(sp, 324.475443431599, 300.0, t, 350, 1, x0)

But I'm getting different values from the single script. Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thank you.
I tried splitting the script into two as seen above.
The values are close to the original but not exact and then reaction completely runsaway. So the way I've split them is very obviously wrong but I can't figure out where.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Here is a script that demonstrates two functions as you requested, with the two essential phases of actuator calculation and measurement retrieval (simulation phase). The reactor is unstable with the PID control and small setpoint changes are needed when in the unstable region.

# PID control based on new measurement
pid.setpoint=sp[i]
u[i+1] = pid(T[i]) + u_bias

# Simulate system for one time step with u[i+1] actuator value
ts = [t[i],t[i+1]]
y = odeint(cstr,x0,ts,args=(u[i+1],Tf,Caf))

It uses the simple_pid package, but you could also code the PID algorithm as a separate, custom function. The inputs are the setpoint and current measured value. The output from the function is the new actuator value. Most industrial applications use the velocity form of the PID equation as shown on the APMonitor course website.

Learning PID control with an unstable system can be frustrating so I recommend learning with some of the other case studies (blending concentration or level) that are stable or with the Temperature Control Lab with physical hardware interface to Python or Matlab / Simulink. Once you get back to the difficult CSTR problem, there are additional approaches such as linear and nonlinear Model Predictive Control.
